# Compress CSV file with GZIP in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, gzip

I need to create a big table to csv file and compress it.

I can create the csv file like this: [Xcode - Create csv/spreadsheet file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659654/xcode-create-csv-spreadsheet-file)

It is possible compress it with GZIP?

Thanks for all.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use SSZipArchive: https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive

Then you can do:

```
NSString *content = @"1,2,3"
NSString *path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"somefile.zip"];
SSZipArchive *zip = [[SSZipArchive alloc] initWithPath:path];
[zip open];
[zip writeData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] filename:@"data.csv"];
[zip close];
```

That will produce a zip file named "somefile.zip" in the temporary directory, containing one file inside named "data.csv"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i need compress with gzip... some idea?

Comment: You're right, I missread the question... I believe you can use this library then: https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP

Comment: GZIP only compress NSData... no CSV.

Comment: I know, but you can easily convert a NSString to NSData: `[someString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to probably not use a standard copy build phase to move the file into place, but instead use shell script build phase to copy the file and then compress it in place with gzip.